# Collision detection between two squares in javascript

Tags: javascript, collision

I've got a problem in my code, I can move the red one (square1) by clicking on it,what I want to do is to detect a collision when the red one touch the blue one. I want it to change colour when there is a collision...

Here is my code to be more clear:
http://jsbin.com/iFAlIyIv/4/edit

Comment: possible duplicate of [Collisions Javascript between two squares](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20283616/collisions-javascript-between-two-squares)

Comment: No, it's another problem...

Comment: Well the question i linked (which you asked and now removed) contained a perfectly good answer on how to detect the collision. To change color you can simply do `square1.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFF00'` // yellow.

Comment: There were a few problems, check out http://jsbin.com/iFAlIyIv/8/edit

Comment: @DaggNabbit Are you putting that in an answer? It would probably make a good one.

Comment: @DutGRIFF, sure, why not :)

Answer (score 1):

Your basic approach was right, the problems were things like this:

- Instead of `square1.left`, you want `square1.offsetLeft`. Elements don't have a `left` property. Same goes for `top`, `width`, and `height`.
- Instead of `document.getElementById("square2")`, you need to select the element by class name, since there's no element with that ID (only an element with that class).
- You're calling `changecouleur`, but you probably meant to call `colorswap`. Looks like a bit of unfinished refactoring.

You also don't need any of the additional checks after this:

```
if (bl > ar || br < al) {
    return false;
} //overlap not possible
if (bt > ab || bb < at) {
    return false;
} //overlap not possible
```

If neither of these conditions are true, they must overlap.

http://jsbin.com/iFAlIyIv/13/edit